# material about IPv6 implementation in linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm looking for books about the IPv6 implementation in linux kernel and differences with the IPv4 implementation. From a first check, I couldn't find any book that discusses the topic thoroughly.

I would appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: try to be more specific. What do you want to do?  write an application? write a kernel-level protocol? netfilter firewall?

Comment: Actually, I don't want to implement something specific. It's just an investigation in the context of an MSc project I have taken over.

Answer (score 0):

you should check [this](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux+IPv6-HOWTO/)

This HOWTO will give you enough information to install, configure, and use IPv6 applications on Linux machines.

Comment: Actually, I'm interested for books that describe the implementation of IPv6 in kernel from code point of view and not on how to setup IPv6.

Answer (score 0):

I think Qing Li's <> is what you want.
But this book don't describe according to the latest kernel, it's about kame project.
IPv6 in Linux kernel cames from kame project.

========
Qing Li (Author), Tatuya Jinmei (Author), Keiichi Shima (Author)

[http://www.amazon.com/Protocols-Implementation-Morgan-Kaufmann-Networking/dp/0124477518/ref=sr_11_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1230096752&sr=11-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0124477518)

Comment: This book looks useful for what I'm looking for, but seems that the content is related to the KAME project which is incorporated in *BSD kernels and not in linux kernels. Am I right?

Comment: different data struct, but same code architecture. The best way is that get the theory by reading this book, and get your answer by looking into source code.

Comment: I think that call flow is also different and it's quite difficult to associate the book with kernel code. Am I correct? Is there any other book I should read?